# Bitmaps in OS design

Tags: user-interface, graphics, bitmap

I have a slightly unusual question about adding graphics to an OS GUI.

When I use a resource viewer I see that there is actually a few different versions of one graphics in the same file, take for example a Windows XP start Menu bitmap:

[image]

There is one graphic for mouseover, one for clicked, and one for clicked. My question, so 3 in total.

My question is, how does it just display the one graphics even though there are three in the file? Here is a real life screen shot of what I mean:

[image]

Also when I view the bitmap resource, it has pink where there would normally be whitespace, what is the reason for that too?

Comment: [About Image Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Also, the pink is used to create a transparency mask.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is no big deal to display just the desired part of the image depending on the state.

As said in the comments, some color can be reserved to indicate transparency which, depending on the viewer, can be rendered differently.

When progressive transparency is supported, you need an alpha plane instead.